# Can I find out if observable was consumed?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

From an offsite storage, I am getting bunch of timestamped XML files which needs to be parsed and processed in order. Parsing of a single file results in Observable which produces stream of records.

The current idea is to read all files in correct order and merge its records into one big stream so consumer doesn't need to care there are multiple files. But caveat is that I need to know which files were already processed and never run them again in the future.

I suppose I am asking too much of Observables here since their purpose is to push data without knowing who consumes them.

Only way I could think of is wrapping each record into a function and consumer calls to get record which also serves as notification for a publisher. So when reading of record from next file has started, I can mark the previous one as processed. But that also means including *blank* callback to know last record from last file was read. That's sort of ugly.

Does anyone have better idea?

**Edit: Thanks to @Picci for providing basic example**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-trtlzc?file=index.ts

```
readFolder('abc')
  .pipe(
    map(orderFileNames),
    switchMap((fileNames) => from(fileNames)),
    concatMap(parseRecordsOfFile)
    // I need to know which records were read so I can persist that for the next run
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: _know which files were already processed and never run them again in the future_ - how do you know if a newly arrived file has already been processed? Do you use some persistent storage for that?

Comment: @AndreiGătej Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the storage is a folder or an AWS Bucket.

I assume also that *"getting bunch of timestamped XML files"* means that you are reading the folder/bucket and get a list of file names.

If this is true, the first event you are interested into is **File Names Read**.

The event **File Names Read** notifies a list of strings `fileNames`, the names of the files, that you have to order by timestamp. The ordering of the list is a `map` operation that returns `orderedFileNames`.

Once you have `orderedFileNames`, you can create a new stream of strings each representing a file name, i.e. a stream which notifies an event for each file name with the rxjs function `from(orderedFileNames)`.

Once you have the stream of file names, than you can take each `fileName` and read a file and generate the *"stream of records"* you are referring to. Since you want to maintain the order, you have to concatenate the transformations of the `fileName`s into the stream of records, therefore you need `concatMap`.

So, all in all, you would have some code that may look like this

```
// the readFolder function returns an Observable that notified the list
// of file names and then completes
readFolder('abc')
  .pipe(
    // orderFileNames returns the ordered list of names
    map((fileNames) => orderFileNames(fileNames)),
    // transform the array of strings into a stream of strings
    switchMap((fileNames) => from(fileNames)),
    // now you concatenate one file name after the other and produce a stream
    // of records for each file name
    // readFile returns an Observable that notifies the content of the file and then completes
    concatMap((fileName) => readFile(fileName))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

[Here a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vmy279?file=index.ts) that runs this code simulating all i/o operations.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I probably wasn't clear enough what's my issue. I am able to assemble stream like this just fine, but I don't see how I can know that a file was consumed and I can remember that, so it's never done again (in case of some failure).

Comment: No prob for the effort, it has been a personal pleasure. However, I confess I do not understand the question then. If you create such a stream and start consuming it via subscription, then any file name will be notified only once and there is no risk of consuming it twice within that stream. Any file name will be notified more than once only if the stream is subscribed more than once. If this is a possibility, maybe as result of error handling, then you are forced to mark the file as processed somehow in some memory. Please correct me if I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: First and foremost this will be regularly executed job, there will be some files and I need to make sure to process each file only once. But if previous run has errored out for some reason, it should still run that fail again. So yes, there is a persistent storage where I keep information which files were processed.

Comment: So probably the problem is to make sure that you update the persistent storage at the end of the processing. If the update operation fails, then you are in an inconsistent state. If this is actually the problem, I do not think Observables can help. If you ignore this potential integrity problem, you have just to read the persistent storage and filter out the files (or the records depending on the granularity) already processed. How to filter depends on the storage. If the storage is read asynchronously, you can compose a slightly more complex stream that has also the storage data.

Answer (score 0):

If parseRecordsOfFile returns some information of the original file, you can use a `distinctUntilChanged` and some custom scan operator (maybe the operator exists?) like:

```
readFolder('abc')
  .pipe(
    map(orderFileNames),
    switchMap((fileNames) => from(fileNames)),
    concatMap(parseRecordsOfFile),
    map(entry => entry.fileName), // or however you access the filename
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    scan(([previous], next) => [next, previous], []),
    map(([next, previous]) => previous),
    filter(Boolean),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log); // now you can subscribe to the completed files
```

If you `parseRecordsOfFiles` does any I/O, you probably have to consider your transaction and your delivery guarantee ("zero or one" vs "one or many").